# How to choose a fixed location for created bag files?

Tags: rosbag, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am creating a rqt plugin at the moment in Python and I am working with bag files.
In the rqt plugin I create new bag files with rosbag.Bag("file_name", "w") and close them later.

Everything works fine but my bag files are always saved in the folder from where I started rqt in console.

Is it possible to choose a fixed folder for this?

I tried to find an answer in older questions but couldn't so I apologize if the question was already asked.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248087/how-to-choose-a-fixed-location-for-created-bag-files-?/) by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For sure the best way to do this is to specify full file paths for the bag file names. Here are a couple of thoughts that would go along with implementing this:

- The first question is what directory to place the bag files in? This depends a bit on exactly what you are doing, but likely the default behavior would be to write the bag files to a particular ROS package directory or some pre-defined directory. If using a ROS package directory, you could use `rospkg`, if using a predefined directory, you'd likely want to use `os.path.expanduser("~")` to get the user's home directory (see example below).
- Secondly, how can the user specify a different directory? You could allow the user to use Qt interfaces to specify the directory, or the user could pass a command line argument or set a ROS private parameter to overwrite the default directory.

Example:

```
import rospkg
import os
fname = "file_name.bag"

# first method
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
pkgpath = rospack.get_path('my_package')
fullpath = os.path.join(pkgpath, fname)

# second method
pkgpath = os.path.expanduser("~")
fullpath = os.path.join(pkgpath, fname)
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2016-11-15**:
Thank you very much for the quick answer. I'll try this!

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2016-11-15**:
It works perfectly. :-) thank you very much